How to convert Java Swing events to Kotlin Flow with maximal performance
I am trying to convert Java Swing events, normally obtained with event listeners, to Kotlin Flow of these events. I checked code of many projects and found more than one way of doing it. I was wondering if someone can give me reasons to use one style over another, in respect to the performance / reliability / resource usage:
fun JButton.actionEvents1(): Flow<ActionEvent> = callbackFlow {
  val listener = ActionListener { e ->
    trySend(e)
  }
  addActionListener(listener)
  awaitClose {
    removeActionListener(listener)
  }
}

fun JButton.actionEvents2(): Flow<ActionEvent> = callbackFlow {
  val listener = ActionListener { e ->
    trySend(e).isSuccess
  }
  addActionListener(listener)
  awaitClose {
    removeActionListener(listener)
  }
}

fun JButton.actionEvents3(): Flow<ActionEvent> = callbackFlow {
  val listener = ActionListener { e ->
    trySendBlocking(e)
  }
  addActionListener(listener)
  awaitClose {
    removeActionListener(listener)
  }
}

fun JButton.actionEvents4(
  scope: CoroutineScope
): Flow<ActionEvent> = callbackFlow {
  val listener = ActionListener { e ->
    scope.launch { send(e) }
  }
  addActionListener(listener)
  awaitClose {
    removeActionListener(listener)
  }
}

The last example is assuming that we have access to the CoroutineScope instance, which in my case would be the same scope from which each action events flow is obtained and collect is called. Should I avoid launching a coroutine for each event?

Any reason not to just do ActionListener { e -> send(e) }? Because trySend will discard the event if the channel happens to be full. Doing send will at least make the coroutine suspend until it can be handled. That would probably maybe make the UI hang, but isn't that better than to discard events when overloaded? Depends on your use-case I'd guess.

I was hoping to use ActionListener { e -> send(e) } as well, but it is forbidden in Kotlin Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body.

Which one to use depends on how you want to handle situations where ActionEvents are issued faster than they can be handled.
The callbackFlow uses a channel internally to decouple sending and receiving the events, acting as a blocking queue. Events from the ActionListener are sent to the channel and are stored there until they are received by the collector of the flow. When the flow collects slower than new events are produced, back-pressure is building up on the channel which is absorbed by the channel's buffer. The buffer, however, is limited (to 64 elements by default), and when the buffer is full new events cannot be sent anymore.
You need to specify what should happen in this situation. There are several options:

Block the current thread until space becomes available.
Suspend the current thread until space becomes available.
Skip the current event.
Drop the oldest event from the buffer to make space for the new event.

Before going into more detail, you can always increase the buffer size, preventing problematic back-pressure situations to arise in the first place. Use .buffer(100) (or whatever buffer size seems appropriate to you) on the callbackFlow { ... }. Beware, though: If you constantly issue events faster than they are handled this will only delay the problem. Only increase the buffer size if you can successfully absorb spikes where a lot of events are issued in bursts.
Option 1 (Block): The trySendBlocking of your actionEvents3 function blocks the main thread that was used to issue the event until the channel isn't full anymore. While the main thread is blocked your UI is unresponsive. You should use this only if there won't be much back-pressure on the channel (i.e., events are usually handled fast enough before the next event is produced).
Option 2 (Suspend): The send of your actionEvents4 function suspends the current thread until the channel isn't full anymore. Suspending the main thread would be good because it allows other code to run on the main thread, keeping your UI responsive. However, it may not even be the main thread that is suspended here because the only thing you do on that thread is launching a new coroutine. That coroutine is what is suspended by send, and that coroutine is launched in the scope you provided. Which may or may not use the main thread, it doesn't matter.
This option is the safest, but it is also the most complicated. If you have serious issues with the back-pressure and cannot skip or drop any events, this may still be the cleanest solution.
Option 3 (Skip): The trySend of your actionEvents1 function backs off from sending the event if the channel is full, effectievly skipping the new event. If this is an appropriate behavior depends on the nature of the events. Repeatedly clicking the same button, so fast that the click event cannot be handled before the next click occurs may be an acceptable situation where the newest click can be ignored.
Your actionEvents2 function behaves identical to actionEvents1. The only difference is that you access isSuccess, determining if the new event was sent successfully. But you do not do anything with that information and immediately end the lambda, so it doesn't matter if it actually was successful or not. You shouldn't use actionEvents2.
Option 4 (Drop): Append .buffer(onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST) to callbackFlow { ... } (you can also specify the buffer size here) and use trySend to send new events. If the channel is full the oldest event will be dropped so the new event can be immediately inserted. This can be useful if you do not need old events and only want to handle the newest events. You may want to actually reduce the buffer size in this case to force all old events to be dropped, instead of keeping old events as they fit in the buffer. Also see if you want to conflate the flow in this situation.

I guess in the code I spotted in some open source projects the trySend(e).isSuccess appears only because it is an equivalent of the old offer function which is now depreciated, and the deprecation message states: replaceWith = ReplaceWith("trySend(element).isSuccess").Indeed it does not provide any value.

There's no one correct way to do this, because the answer depends on the behavior you're looking for. You need to decide what you want to happen in the unlikely event that the button is clicked repeatedly, faster than the application can respond to it.
There are really three possible solutions.

Drop the extra events. Whether you want this behavior will depend on what the button actually does. You can get this behavior by combining trySend with a small or non-existent buffer. Some clicks will be ignored when the application is busy.
Block the UI until the program catches up. Instinctively, this might feel wrong—blocking the UI thread is bad. But in fact, it might be a viable solution, since it will prevent the user from making any more inputs until the application is ready to handle them. This is what you'll get if you use trySendBlocking when the flow's buffer is full.
Buffer the events in a queue. You can get this behavior if you combine trySend or trySendBlocking with a large enough buffer. Every single click will eventually be handled, one by one.

A flow's buffer size can be changed by chaining a call to buffer() or conflate().
A sensible strategy is probably a hybrid:

Add a buffer that's large enough to handle the rough number of events you expect. Since we're dealing with button clicks, this probably won't be large.
If the buffer gets full, either block the UI, or drop the events.

Once you decide which behavior you want, the implementation mostly chooses itself.
You'll notice I didn't mention the launch { send(…) } version. In fact, this is really just a variation on using large/unlimited buffer. If the new coroutine can't send its event immediately, it will suspend and wait in a dispatch queue until it can. So there's still a buffer; it's just concealed in the coroutine machinery. Using an explicit buffer() on the flow makes the intent clearer, and (at a guess) is likely to be more performant anyway.
Note that if you do want to use launch(), you don't need to provide a scope, since the callbackFlow already has its own.
